# Find derivative of a function with Abs in python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, sympy, derivative

I would like to compute derivative of `y=Abs(0.5-0.5*sqrt(1-4*x))` in 0.1, using python.
This is my code:

```
x=Symbol('x')
y=Abs(0.5-0.5*sqrt(1-4*x))
deriv=y.diff(x)
d=lambdify(x,deriv,'numpy')
print d(0.1)
```

This is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/milossimic/g4/s1/.../optimize.py", line 100, in <module>
    print d(0.1)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: global name 'Derivative' is not defined
```

I'm a newbie to `sympy` and `numpy`, so I guess I'm using the wrong method to determine derivative.

EDIT: I printed deriv and this is what I got:

[image]

After reading this http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/functions/elementary.html, I've tried `fdiff()`:

```
x=Symbol('x')
y=Abs(0.5-0.5*sqrt(1-4*x))
deriv=y.fdiff()
d=lambdify(x,deriv,'numpy')
print d(0)
```

But after experimenting with other values to compute derivative, I figured out that the result is -1, 0 or 1 because `deriv` is actually `sign(-0.5*sqrt(-4*x + 1) + 0.5)`.

What should I do?

Both numpy and sympy are imported:

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
```

If I try to find derivative of a function that is not under Abs, there are no problems.

Comment: Just as a side note: At `x=0` your function is not differentiable. I don't know how simpy handles this though. Have you tried other `x` values?

Comment: I did, but it is always the same: global name 'Derivative' is not defined, no matter what x I choose. : )

Comment: I checked your initial code with my setup, I get the error `NameError: global name 'Abs' is not defined`, but only if I choose `'numpy'` as module. Without or with `('numpy','sympy')` it works. However you will still get a division error at `x=0`.

Comment: It's always the error `NameError: global name 'Derivative' is not defined`.

Comment: The `NameError: global name 'Abs' is not defined` is due to an bug in my old version of sympy and probably not connected with your issue.

Comment: The second method is obviously wrong, the only thing `fdiff` did is replace `Abs` with `sign` as the documentation you posted points out if you click on `source`. At `x=0` there is no derivative.

Comment: Yes, there isn't derivative at x=0. I'll edit the question now, but the problem will remain the same, in terms of error returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want the derivative of `Abs` to be `sign`. SymPy does do this, but only if it can deduce that the argument to the absolute value is real, which it can't in this case (even if `x` is real).

You can make your own custom version of `Abs` that always uses `sign` pretty easily by subclassing and overriding the `_eval_derivative` method:

```
class MyAbs(Abs):
    def _eval_derivative(self, x):
        return Derivative(self.args[0], x, evaluate=True)*sign(conjugate(self.args[0]))
```

.

```
In [110]: x = Symbol('x')

In [111]: y = MyAbs(0.5-0.5*sqrt(1-4*x))

In [112]: deriv = y.diff(x)

In [113]: print(deriv)
1.0*sign(-0.5*conjugate(sqrt(-4*x + 1)) + 0.5)/sqrt(-4*x + 1)

In [114]: lambdify(x, deriv, 'numpy')(0.1)
Out[114]: 1.29099444874
```

Answer (score 6):

This is more a mathematical problem than anything else.

```
>>> import sympy
>>> x = sympy.symbols('x')
>>> def f(x):
...  return abs(x)
... 
>>> dx = f(x).diff(x)
>>> dx
(re(x)*Derivative(re(x), x) + im(x)*Derivative(im(x), x))/Abs(x)
```

Notice there is a real part and an imaginary part. abs(x) is differentiable at every real x, but zero. However, there are [issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Derivative) when it comes to complex values (which I can't explain since I don't know complex differentiation). I guess sympy doesn't have an implementation for that, and thus returns `Derivative(f)` instead of the actual derivative of f.

If you're working only with real numbers, then just use `x = sympy.symbols('x', real=True)`:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> x = sympy.symbols('x', real=True)
>>> def f(x):
...  return abs(0.5-0.5*(1-4*x)**0.5)
... 
>>> dx = f(x).diff(x)
>>> dx
(1.0*(-0.5*re((-4*x + 1)**0.5) + 0.5)*re((-4*x + 1)**(-0.5)) - 0.5*im((-4*x + 1)**(-0.5))*im((-4*x + 1)**0.5))/Abs(-0.5*(-4*x + 1)**0.5 + 0.5)
>>> dx_ = sympy.lambdify(x, dx)
>>> dx_(0.1)
1.2909944487358056
```

Comment: Which version of python/sympy are you using? I get `re(x)/Abs(x)` as result for `dx` in your first code block with python 2.7 and sympy 0.7.1.rc1, which is probably why I couldn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Nabla that SymPy version is quite old. 0.7.4.1 gives what Alex got.

Comment: Another thing to note, if you plan to enter values such that the square roots become complex, you'll need to input a numpy array with complex dtype, or else you will get a TypeError because numpy's sqrt refuses to work with negative real numbers.

Comment: This solution is so much better and easier. Thank you!

Comment: I think we should reopen this one, I have issues if lambdify is to work on a NumPy array. I always get global name Abs or MyAbs is not defined. I post a new question